# Hi i am trying to make this scene but i am still new to blender please help

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to make this scifi object and there are so many small and big panels. When I make them glow they don't look like seperate objects they just look like a big panel.

This is a scene from SAO ending 'unlasting'
[image]

Comment: Edit your title to something more relevant to your question (in short). Attach screens of your result and setup you use or share your simplified blend via https://blend-exchange.com/ ... thank you

Comment: what you show also looks like on big panel, except some have a different color, so maybe you should use a particle system with a collection as particle and give a different color to some of the objects of this collection?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a particle and non-geometry node solution.

In your picture they also look like one big object except some of the planes have a different color. You can create a cube, stretch it a bit on Z, and give it a particle system with a collection of several planes:

[image]

Create several plane, give them a material with an *Emission* that has a *Strength* higher than 1 in order to make them glow later, give a different color to one of your particles, put them in a new collection. Select the cube, give it a particle system, enable *Advanced*, choose the amount of particles, *Source > Volume*, enable *Rotation*, choose *Global Z* axis:

[image]

Under Render choose *Render As > Collection*, choose the scale of the particles and if you want a bit of scale randomness, disable *Show Emitter*, select the particle collection. To vary the amount of each particle, enable *Use Count* and set the amount. Under *Viewport Display* disable *Show Emitter*:

[image]